# Vue 3 props validation along with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I want to create a custom `Link` component with Nuxt, Typescript and the composition-api.
`target` is a prop that can take predefined values such as shown below.
If I understand well, a custom `validator` function can check prop type at runtime whereas Typescript types are only static?

Is it useful to combine both?

```
import { defineComponent } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Link',
  props: {
    target: {
      type: String as () => '_self' | '_blank' | '_parent' | '_top',
      default: '_self',
      validator: (value: string) => {
        return ['_self', '_blank', '_parent', '_top'].includes(value);
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that TypeScript types are checked only during build-time, and `validator()`s are runtime guards.

Vue and TypeScript's relationship is ... complicated. You might've used React before where `<Link target="some_invalid_value"/>` would throw a TypeScript error without much extra configuration. In Vue I'd say getting such an error (ie. getting TS prop validation in the template) is considered "new".

If you can get the fancy developer-experience enhancing extensions to work,  using TypeScript is more comfortable. But keep in mind that:

- TypeScript prop validation is pretty experimental/unstable
- Those extensions will work only within VSCode, but if you run `npm run build` you probably won't get errors (unless you use something like https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/tree/master/vti - which is an addon for Vetur. It will report the same errors you'd get when viewing a "bad" file in VSCode, but it'll do that in terminal in CI and it can fail a build if it sees errors).

However if you expect that other people will use your Link component in different places - for example if you're making a component library - consider it may be used in:

- projects where there's no TypeScript
- projects that don't even use webpack and use Vue in raw .html files

which won't benefit from your TypeScript types, but can benefit from validator().

Can you check if you use your `Link` component in another component, then pass `<Link target="some_invalid_value"/>` if you get TypeScript errors? If not, you need to do some extra configuration with those extensions (VSCode only):

- https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar
- https://github.com/znck/vue-developer-experience

---

Some extra tips:

I noticed that the type assertion (`as`) you're using non-standard. Seems like the Vue docs https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props guide users to use `as PropType`

Probably don't use single-word component names. It's the first rule in the styleguide and it's marked as "Essential":
https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide/#multi-word-component-names-essential

Comment: I'll check out the extensions you linked. For the extra tips, you might be right for the Typescript typing, I took this example from https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/cookbook/components which not might be up to date. For single-word component-names, I use Nuxt, so components are auto-imported and prefix with their current folders in the components directory. So, no risk to override a native component. Thanks for your detailed answer!